# Get DataAnnotation errors from an object

Tags: silverlight, validation

I'm using DataAnnotations for Silverlight user input validation.

I want to get every error in an object before save it.

I'll be executing the Validator.ValidateProperty foreach of its properties and I want to know if every problem has been solved before letting user save.

It would be cool to raise a "validate all properties" method, is this possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidationSummary has a "HasError" Property you can use to send as a CommandParameter to de View Model.